# many to many relationship adding items

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, asp.net-4.5

I'm using the following two classes as suggested in this website: https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

```
   public class Barca
   {
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int BarcaID { get; set; } 
    public virtual ICollection<Imbarco> Imbarco { get; set; }
    public virtual Imbarco ImbarcoBase { get; set; }
    }

   public class Imbarco
   {
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] 
    public int ImbarcoID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Barca> Barche { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Barca> BaseBarche { get; set; }
    }
```

I need to create 1 to M relationship and for that I used these 2 navigation properties:

```
public virtual Imbarco ImbarcoBase { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Barca> BaseBarche { get; set; }
```

but I need also a M to M relationship and for that I used:

```
public virtual ICollection<Imbarco> Imbarco { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Barca> Barche { get; set; }
```

when I try to add a new item in the M to M, the bridge table is not created in the database, as described in the link reported above and also the edmx file I tried to generate in VisualStudio created a 0..1 to M and a M to 0..1 relationship instead of m to M.
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You probably need another class to represent the bridge (junction) table which has the two foreign keys to the other tables as properties.

Comment: I found what you suggest in a forum of 2014 but I suppose the bridge table is created automatically in EF6 as described here https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx, or am I wrong ?

Comment: Did you add the collections initializations at the constructor of each class?

Comment: Do you mean something like:                                                                                                   public Barca() 
    {
        this.Imbarco = new HashSet<Imbarco>();
    }                                                                                                                                             No, I didn't add them... I try now

Comment: @WMmaster I think that would depend on if you are using the `code-first` approach with `EF`.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by fixing your model. I recommend you configure with [fluent api](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/fluent-api-in-code-first.aspx), but you can try the [InverseProperty annotation](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inverseproperty-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx) so EF makes the proper connections:

```
   public class Imbarco
   {
       [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] 
       public int ImbarcoID { get; set; }

       [InverseProperty("Imbarco")]
       public virtual ICollection<Barca> Barche { get; set; }
       [InverseProperty("ImbarcoBase")]
       public virtual ICollection<Barca> BaseBarche { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Using your suggestion I receive now the following error message:                       
index 'IX_ImbarcoBase_ImbarcoID' dependent by 'ImbarcoBase_ImbarcoID'.
object 'FK_dbo.Barcas_dbo.Imbarcoes_ImbarcoBase_ImbarcoID' dependent by column 'ImbarcoBase_ImbarcoID'.
Impossible to execute ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN ImbarcoBase_ImbarcoID because one or more objects are using it. But why it's trying to drop ImbarcoBase ? it was for the 1 to many relationship that was working fine

Comment: Yeah, EF probably added another ImbarcoID for the 2nd relationship. Either rebuild it all or you could use fluent code to match the FKs properly.

Comment: How can I reply to your post with more characters ? I tried to use add-migrations and update-database but I can't show you the result

Comment: I received the error "Either the parameter objname is ambiguous or the claimed objtype (COLUMN) is wrong" even if the add-migrations would like to create the bridge table so I suppose i was in the right direction

Comment: Edit your question when you need to add additional information. What is confusing is I see now you mention an `edmx` and migrations. They do not coexist. EDMX is database first, migrations are code first.

Comment: I'm using code first... I tried to generate the edmx file from a source code copy only to see the result from database point of view and there I realized it was creating a wrong match betweeen the properties